# Ways to interpolate template variables inside JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, json, string-interpolation, underscore.js-templating

I'd like to do the following

```
var obj = {
  animal: "${animal}"
};

var res = magic(obj, {animal: "cat"});

// res => {animal: "cat"}
```

`magic` is some function that does the dirty work. Obviously `obj` could be more complex with multiple keys, nested arrays and so on. The template variable could be inside an array like this

```
var obj = {
  animals: ["cat", "dog", "${animal}", "cow"]
};
```

and it could be anywhere in the array so simply doing `obj.animals[2] = "bat";` isn't feasible.

I've found the [underscore-tpl library](https://github.com/creynders/underscore-tpl) with which I can achieve what I want, but I would like to know if there are other solutions for future reference and because I had a hard time finding underscore-tpl in the first place.

My actual use is case is that I have a config.json file where I have several declarations like the following

```
{
  "task1": {
    "command": "command-line-program",
    "args": [
      "--input", "{{input}}",
      "--flag1",
      "--output", "{{output}}",
      "--flag2",
    ],
    "options": {
      "cwd": "path-to-working-dir"
    }
  }
}
```

I parse this consig.json using `JSON.parse(...)` and I call `require("child_process").spawn` with the `command`, `args` and `options` parameters declared in the file, however `args` change a lot, flags added, reordered and stuff, so simply doing `config.task1.args[1] = "<input value>";` involves changing the code that invokes `spawn` and this is as error prone as it gets.

## Update

Based on [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31729231) I've created a simple package ([located here](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/tplobj)) which I can include in my projects, feel free to use it.

Comment: Why not just `animal: res.animal`?  If you need the interpolation in the middle of a larger string, checkout ES2015 [template strings](http://es6-features.org/#StringInterpolation). *edit* oh OK I see what you're getting at.

Comment: Look for JS template engines. Note that asking for off-site resources, libraries, etc. is actually OT for SO.

Comment: @DaveNewton Well I admit this isn't the best all time SO question :) I really just wanted to put something "out there", so that I (and others) could find it more easily, because I had a hard time finding a painless solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `JSON.stringify` the object, then replace your search value with the actual value, then `JSON.parse` the result:

```
function magic(o, a) {
    var j = JSON.stringify(o);
    for (var k in a) {
            j = j.split('${'+k+'}').join(a[k]);
    }
    return JSON.parse(j);
}
```

Comment: I've tried something like this, only with regexes doing "search and replace" on my whole config.json. I had issues with escaping quotes stuff while parsing back the string to JSON, but in general, yeah this works :)

Comment: Well, I've stayed with your suggestion, because this couldn't get more simple. I've created a package based on this [here](https://github.com/kohanyirobert/tplobj). I updated the code so that `a[k]` would get properly escaped. So far it works for me. Thanks for idea!

Comment: This solution seems destined to break unexpectedly, because it doesn't escape the strings in `a`.  (i.e., it'll work on simple test cases, but then break in production when you get a string that contains a quote or backslash or somesuch)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you a very simple but very fast and **understandable** template engine:
[simple-template.js](https://github.com/snoguchi/simple-template.js/blob/master/simple-template.js)

It consists of 22 lines of code, very simple!
Considering that, you will be able to render your config easily!